# (listAdapter as WiFiPeerListAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged() Causing Crash

Tags: android, wifi-direct

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    listAdapter = WiFiPeerListAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.row_devices, peers)
}
```

**causing crash while casting as below:**

```
   fun clearPeers() {
    peers.clear()
    (listAdapter as WiFiPeerListAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

**here list adapter is setListAdapter() from ListFragment() class:**

```
  public void setListAdapter(@Nullable ListAdapter adapter) {
    boolean hadAdapter = mAdapter != null;
    mAdapter = adapter;
    if (mList != null) {
        mList.setAdapter(adapter);
        if (!mListShown && !hadAdapter) {
            // The list was hidden, and previously didn't have an
            // adapter.  It is now time to show it.
            setListShown(true, requireView().getWindowToken() != null);
        }
    }
}
```

Crash Report:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.tsfapps.wifip2p, PID: 29222
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.wifi.p2p.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGE flg=0x24000010 (has extras) } in com.tsfapps.wifip2p.WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver@b154cba
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1689)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.tsfapps.wifip2p.DeviceListFragment.WiFiPeerListAdapter
at com.tsfapps.wifip2p.DeviceListFragment.clearPeers(DeviceListFragment.kt:102)
at com.tsfapps.wifip2p.MainActivity.resetData(MainActivity.kt:159)
at com.tsfapps.wifip2p.WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver.kt:77)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1679)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)

I tried to search in Goolge, but not got any proper solution

Answer (score 0):

The crash you face is caused by a NullPointerException when cast the listAdapter to WifiPeerListAdaptor . The exception occurs because the listAdapter are null the time of casting.

To fix the crash listAdapter is properly initialized before calling the clearPeer() function.

**Here is an Example**

```
private lateinit var listAdapter: WiFiPeerListAdapter 

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    listAdapter = WiFiPeerListAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.row_devices, peers)

    // Other code...
}

fun clearPeers() {
    peers.clear()

    // Check if listAdapter is initialized

    if (::listAdapter.isInitialized) { 
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```